# I get an error in the startActionMode() Method

Tags: java, android

I get an error in the `startActionMode()` method. With `Cast parameter to android.view.ActionMode.Callback` expression says I have to do casting transaction but it is not the solution. I don't know this problem.

You can look at the code:

```
package com.egemenzeytinci.contextmenuactionmode;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private android.view.ActionMode actionMode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if(actionMode!=null) {
                return false;
            }

            MyActionModeCallBack callBack=new MyActionModeCallBack();
            actionMode=startActionMode(callBack); //problem is here!!!
            v.setSelected(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

class MyActionModeCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        actionMode=null;
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
private ActionMode actionMode;
```

Not this:

```
private android.view.ActionMode actionMode;
```

And should be like this:

```
actionMode=startSupportActionMode(callBack);
```

Not this:

```
actionMode=startActionMode(callBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need a reference of Action mode to implement it. Hence, instead of calling the method `actionMode=startActionMode(callBack);` this way, call it this way `startActionMode(callBack);` This shall do.

Comment: I try this: startActionMode ((android.view.ActionMode.Callback) callBack); does not give an error but this time the simulator does not open the application.

Comment: There must be some error otherwise the application must open.

Answer (score 0):

class MyActionModeCallBack implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {

  }
```

}}

Comment: Use this  android.view.ActionMode.Callback  in the place of ActionMode.Callback hope it will work thnku